# High ANR rate on Play Console Vitals since mid-December 2023

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-vitals

Since mid-December my app ANR rate spiked from 0.30% to 0.60% (bad behavior) in the Google Play Console vitals section without any change to the app.

[image]

In the Play Console there's the following note on December 16th:

> The way data is collected from Android 9 devices has changed, and
> Android 8 devices are no longer used to calculate crash and ANR rates.
> As a result, you may notice changes to the reported crash and ANR
> rates for these Android versions.

Drilling down I can see the following on the ANRs:

1. All top 5 devices with high ANR rate are Huawei (Y6 Pro 2019, Y5 2019, Y9 2019, Y6s, Y9s). Not sure if those devices come with Google Play (some places say they do, some say they do not).
2. Android 9 shows 1.7% ANR, the rest are below 0.4%
3. The app versions with high ANR rate are 6+ years old.
4. The high ANR rate comes from one country.
5. Could not find those ANRs in the Statistics -> Quality report in Google Play Console. Only in the vitals.

It looks like side loading old app versions from unknown 3rd marketplace is causing this.

The [documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9844486?hl=en#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20Android%20vitals%20metrics%20exclude,not%20installed%20through%20Google%20Play.) states that:

> Android vitals metrics exclude technical issues that occur on
> uncertified device models, or on versions of your app that were not
> installed through Google Play.

Anything I can do?